# React-table custom cells cause re-render in every change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I need help with React-table.
I have a table that has rows with custom components (Select components and editable input).
When I change the Select/editable input the whole table is re-rendering .
how can I prevent it from happened?

I try to wrap my custom components with React.memo but I did not success to handle the problem.

[This is a link for sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-firefly-djpsi7?file=/src/View.jsx:3584-3601)

you can see in the console that if you change the input it renders everything.

P.S don't use the last column something doesn't work there (i copied it from my project)
thanks!